# Connection string method wrong. Login failed for user

Tags: c#, .net

I have a connection string:

```
public static string str = "Data Source=SAI-7FD4677573D\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Libary;";
```

But getting an error:

> Cannot open database "Libary" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'SAI-7FD4677573D\Administrator'.

How can I write a connection string?

```
public static string str = "Data Source=SAI-7FD4677573D\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=SAI-7FD4677573D\Administrator;Initial Catalog=Libary;";
```

Please help what should I try?

Comment: First of all don't reveal original data source on stackoverflow. Second use `SQLConnectionBuilder` class.

Comment: `Integrated Security=True` and remove `User Id` if you want to use Windows Authentication

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal -- It's just a SQL Express db on his/her local machine.  NBD.

Comment: I tried that but still error

Comment: Does the database exist? Isn't it `Library` for example?

Comment: is "Libary" a typo? shouldn't be "Library"?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad he has used escape char "\\" so he should not use "@"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a typo. shouldn't be `Library` instead of `Libary`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data source, you seem to be using SQL Server Express.  What you will need to do in order to use integrated security is to use SQL Server Management Studio to setup a login for your Windows user account and then create a "user" account for that login on your database.

What user account did you use to install SQL Server Express on your computer?  It was probably a local administrator.  So, log off, and log back on as that local administrator (or any local administrator or user who is in the "Administrators" group on your PC), and run SQL Server Management Studio (alternatively, you could hold down the shift key, right-click on SQL Server Management Studio, and select "Run as different user", and then enter your local administrator account).  Then go to the "Security" > "Logins" section in "Object Explorer", right-click and select "New Login", then click "Search" and enter the local user account.

Next, select "User Mapping" under "Select a page" on the left-hand side, and put a checkmark next to your database in the list.  In the database role membership below that, you can configure the base roles that your user will have, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can support two kinds of user authentication:
Windows based authentication & user/password authentication.
* Windows based authentication (also called "Integrated security)) is using your Windows login as medium of athentication. In this case you shouldn't proveide "User Id" and "Password" fields in the connection string and the "Integrated Security" param must be set to "true".
* Username/Password based. If you want to use explicitely defined username & password to access SQL Server database, "User Id" **and** "Password" fields in the connection string have to be specified and the "Integrated Security" param must be set to "false".

Bottom line - Your connection string contains both "Integrated security=true" and "User Id" param provided, which is an error. In case you need Windows authentication - remove User Id, otherwise add "Password" param and set "Integrated security" to false